# Scrollbar not functioning properly Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, scrollbar

I am a newbie to Python.

I am trying to create a Scrollbar, which I did but the scrollbar is not functioning properly.

The frame already shows all labels but what I expected was the frame will only show up to 5 labels

and if frame contains more than 5 labels, then the scrollbar will function to show the unseen remaining labels.

Any help?

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        root=Tk()
        frame=Frame(root,width=300,height=300)
        frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.canvas=Canvas(frame,bg='#FFFFFF',width=300,height=300,scrollregion=(0,0,500,500))
        Label(self.canvas,text="1").pack()
        Label(self.canvas,text="2").pack()
        Label(self.canvas,text="3").pack()
        Label(self.canvas,text="4").pack()
        Label(self.canvas,text="5").pack()
        Label(self.canvas,text="6").pack()
        Label(self.canvas,text="1").pack()
        Label(self.canvas,text="2").pack()
        Label(self.canvas,text="3").pack()
        Label(self.canvas,text="4").pack()
        Label(self.canvas,text="5").pack()
        Label(self.canvas,text="6").pack()
        hbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=HORIZONTAL)
        hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
        hbar.config(command=self.canvas.xview)
        vbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=VERTICAL)
        vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>',self._On_Configure())

        vbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.config(width=300,height=300)
        self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH)
        root.mainloop()
    def _On_Configure(self):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))

GUI = GUI()
```

Answer (score 0):

I will not implement it for you. Here are some methods which you might be interested in:

```
from Tkinter import *

class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
    root=Tk()
    frame=Frame(root,width=300,height=300)
    frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
    self.canvas=Canvas(frame,bg='#FFFFFF',width=300,height=300,scrollregion=(0,0,500,500))
    self.canvas_frame = Frame(self.canvas)
    self.canvas.create_window(0,0, anchor = NW, window = self.canvas_frame)
    self.labels = []
    for i in range(10):
        label = Label(self.canvas_frame,text=str(i))
        label.pack()
        self.labels.append(label)
    hbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=HORIZONTAL)
    hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
    hbar.config(command=self.canvas.xview)
    vbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=VERTICAL)
    vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

    self.canvas.bind('<Configure>',self._On_Configure) # MISTAKE! do not use () here

    vbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
    self.canvas.config(width=300,height=300)
    self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
    self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH)
    root.mainloop()
    def _On_Configure(self, event = None):
        print self.canvas.bbox(self.canvas_frame)
        for label in self.labels:
            print label.winfo_pointerxy(), label.winfo_rootx(), label.winfo_rooty(), label.winfo_height(), label.winfo_reqheight()
        print "canvas:", self.canvas.winfo_height(), self.canvas.winfo_pointerxy()
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(self.canvas_frame))

GUI = GUI()
```

The output shows the position of the labels and other pixel stuff.

```
None
(664, 607) 0 0 21 21
(664, 607) 0 21 21 21
(664, 607) 0 42 21 21
(664, 607) 0 63 21 21
(664, 607) 0 84 21 21
(664, 607) 0 105 21 21
(664, 607) 0 126 21 21
(664, 607) 0 147 21 21
(664, 607) 0 168 21 21
(664, 607) 0 189 21 21
canvas: 304 (664, 607)
```

With the knowledge about how big the labels are or how big the frame is you can use store the `vbar` in `self.vbar` and do `self.vbar.pack_forget()` or `vbar.pack()` whenever you need it or not in the function `_On_Configure`.

When you have your code ready for a scrolled frame then please do not hesitate to post it. 
I remember other people also lloking for a frame with scrollbars.